# WordPress sitemap with the Google XML Sitemaps plugin

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap

I installed the plugin and as expected the sitemap should be visible on domainname.com/sitemap.xml. It is visible, but like shown in the photo. I don't have posts, only pages. The list of the pages links is only visible when I click on one of the sub-sitemaps links. How to remove them? Thank you.[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

A sitemap index file is like a master sitemap file.

**Basics** (Which I am sure you are already aware of)
A sitemap is a set of links which a crawler will file and index.
A master sitemap file is a link to other sitemap files.

Google fully understands the process of a sitemap index file and will work with it very well. So if you are concerned about your pages getting indexed, sitemap index file will do just fine. It even has more [advantage](http://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/google-xml-sitemap-generator-new-sitemap-format/)s over normal sitemap file.

**Don't want to have sub sitemap files?**

If you are still looking for a normal sitemap file with, you can downgrade the version of your current plugin to 3.x version as version 4 supports only the new format. If you don't want to downgrade, you can use other plugins like yoast. Both will do just fine.

P.S. If your site has proper navigation and no island pages, submitting a sitemap is not necessary at all. Google will do its job.

Comment: That is great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here. You can upload each individual sitemap in to Search Console and it'll be fine :)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about your plugin however the easiest solution is to just write them up in notepad++ or a text editor and submit them yourself.